# Does changing a global variable in a recursive function change the top level

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, global-variables

I have a global dictionary variable and I am trying to call a recursive function that going down a few levels depending on which key it is trying to find and then changes that value.

I am wondering why it isn't changing the global variable when I change a branch of it in my function.

So my recursive function looks like this:

```
def update_dict_with_edits(base_system_dict, changed_json_dict):
    name = changed_json_dict["base_system"]["name"]
    if "base_system" not in base_system_dict:
        return
    sub_dict = base_system_dict["base_system"]
    if name == sub_dict["name"]:
        print(name)
        print("found it and updating")
        sub_dict = changed_json_dict
        # even if I print out here the_global_dict_object it is unaltered
        # print(the_global_dict_object)
        return
    if "sub_systems" not in sub_dict:
        return
    for d in sub_dict["sub_systems"]:
        update_dict_with_edits(d, changed_json_dict)
```

And I call it here:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        the_json = request.form.get('json_data', None)
        the_json = json.loads(the_json)
        update_dict_with_edits(the_global_dict_object, the_json)
        # here when I print out the_global_dict_object it is unaltered
        # print(the_global_dict_object)
        # but here when I render the variable the_json just to view it,
        # it is correctly edited but the change just doesn't happen in
        # the function
        return render_template('testing.html', the_json=the_json)
```

I'm using flask but I don't think it is all that relevant.

Comment: You are not assigning *anything* to the dictionaries. No dictionary is being mutated, *anywhere in your code*.

Comment: But generally speaking, if you pass in a dictionary, then *mutate* that dictionary (add key-value pairs, alter values, delete keys) then that change is visible to any other references to that same dictionary.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear but I thought the variable names were somewhat self explanatory and I didn't want to go into too much depth. Where I call the function, the variable "the_json" is the changed dictionary, it is a subsection of the whole one that I've taked out and altered and now I am trying to assign that changed section back to the main one.

Comment: So base_system_dict is the whole thing, and changed_json_dict is a subsection that I've taken out, a user has altered in a GUI, and now I'm putting it back in.

Comment: But you are not assigning anything to any keys of `base_system_dict` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [changing a *name*, not mutating a reference](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/):

```
# Assign a dict to the name `sub_dict`
sub_dict = base_system_dict["base_system"]
if name == sub_dict["name"]:
    # Update *that name* to point at a new dictionary
    sub_dict = changed_json_dict
```

Instead, update the reference in `base_system_dict`:

```
if name == sub_dict["name"]:
    # Update *the reference* to point at a new dictionary
    base_system_dict["base_system"] = changed_json_dict
```